# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app.project'

Tags: python, django

Mb I am idiot but I wanna know what I do wrong

i think my problem is here

setting.py

```
  INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'app.project',
]
```

or here

urls.py

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path
    from app.project import views

    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.index, admin.site.urls),
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ]
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKFI5.png)
and
[packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUBmv.png)

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start Django from the first `app` directory via `python ./manage.py runserver`, then the `app` is your base directory, you don't have to append `app` to your module called `project`.

The corrected settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  'django.contrib.admin',
  'django.contrib.auth',
  'django.contrib.contenttypes',
  'django.contrib.sessions',
  'django.contrib.messages',
  'django.contrib.staticfiles',
  'project',
]
```

URLs:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from project import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, admin.site.urls),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone has moved their app into another folder such as an `apps` folder (which I typically do), you'd have to use `apps.your_app_name` in the installed apps and then in your apps.py file, change the name to `apps.your_app_name`.